# Magento 2 looking in /en_US/ and can't find my files

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm trying to theme a magento website, however I already ran into some problems.

I'm following [THIS](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/finalize-custom-theme-magento-2/) guide.

However when I refresh my page, Magento can't find my styling or my custom logo and I can't find out why.

here is my ***Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml file:***

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/mt_logo.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">300</argument> 
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

this is the error I'm receiving in my console:

> GET
>   http://localhost:8888/magento/pub/static/frontend/Nicolas/mytheme/en_US/images/mt-logo.png
>   404 (Not Found)

My logo is saved in ***mytheme/web/images***

How do I solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I've written following detail post about Magento2 theme development. You may follow this as well.

https://magento2training.com/2016/07/06/creating-a-magento-2-theme/

Answer (score 0):

Try it with below command

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Delete **pub/statti/***

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```